# Issues creating custom post, wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm attempting to build my first wordpress plugin with the goal of creating a 'recipe' custom post type. I'm running into issues while adding test posts. I am able to create new 'recipe' posts and they display in the 'recipe' custom post backend but I am unable to get the custom posts to add to the regular post feed, also the post links return an oops Page not Found error.

So in short I am able to create a new custom post type, but the new custom post does not show in the normal blog feed and the created custom post when the post is engaged returns a page not found error.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'recipe_custom_post_type');
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'recipes_messages' );

    function recipe_custom_post_type()  {
        $labels = array(
            'name'      =>      'Recipes',
            'singular_name' =>  'Recipe',
            'menu_name'     =>  'Recipe',
            'name_admin_bar'=>  'Recipe',
            'add_new'       =>  'Add New',
            'add_new_item'  =>  'Add New Recipe',
            'edit_item'     =>  'New Recipe',
            'view_item'     =>  'View Recipe',
            'all_items'     =>  'All Recipes',
            'search_items'  =>  'Search Recipes',
            'parent_item_colon' =>  'Parent Recipes:',
            'not_found'         =>  'No Recipes Found:(',
            'not_found_in_trash'    =>  'No Recipes Found in Trash:('
        );

        $args = array(
            'public'        => true,
            'labels'        =>  $labels,
            'rewrite'       =>  array(  'slug'  =>  'recipe'),
            'has_archive'   =>  true,
            'menu_position' =>  20,
            'menu_icon'     =>  'dashicons-carrot',
            'taxonomies'    =>  array(  'post_tag' ,    'category'),
            'supports'      =>  array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'comments' )
        );

            register_post_type( 'recipe',   $args);

    }


    function recipes_messages(  $messages   )  {
        $post   =   get_post();

        $messages['recipe'] =   array(
            0   =>  '',
            1   =>  'Recipe Updated.',
            2   =>  'Custom Field Updated.',
            3   =>  'Custom Field Deleted.',
            4   =>  'Recipe Updated.',
            5  => isset( $_GET['revision'] ) ? sprintf( 'Recipe restored to revision from %s',wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false, 
            6   =>  'Recipe Published.',
            7   =>  'Recipe Saved.',
            8   =>  'Recipe Submitted.',
            9   =>  sprintf('Recipe scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>.',
                        date_i18n( 'M j, Y @ G:i', strtotime( $post->post_date ) )  ),
            10  =>  'Recipe draft updated.'    
        );

        return $messages;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Did you re-save your permalinks after activating your plugin?

Comment: I did not do that, what is the benefit of re-saving permalinks?

Comment: Re-saving the permalinks did solve the issue with the custom posts returning page not found error. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: AFAIK WordPress caches its permalink rule. When you register new posts types WordPress doesn't have rules for them (hence the 404 errors you were seeing). Saving the permalinks makes WordPress rebuild said rules.

Comment: Great that's good to know for future reference. Thanks for taking the time to explain!